# Prestashop 1.7.4.2 - add to cart ajax very slow (TTFB 3 seconds)

Tags: ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with add to cart button. After I pressed, I need wait 4 - 6 seconds. If you open console, you will see 3 calls with 2 - 3 seconds every.
The wesite is: https://wowpet.ro .

I tried:

1. Disabled all modules. - (themes modules, core modules)
2. Disabled override.
3. Clear cache/ changed settings for cache (minify js, css etc).
4. Activated debug - (nothing happened)
5. Checked err_log file (nothing wrong)
6. I moved the shop in another host (same time)
7. Enabled/disabled ajax cart from module.
8. Updated at 1.7.6.7 but I got an error 500 in homepage. (I restored 1.7.4.2).

Can you help me with a suggestion?

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. How did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in one of the PrestaShop version, where due too high timeout set inside core javascript files, we could see slow processing of this request. I suggest to work on an update to newer version, of course you'll need to do that on some dev version, not directly on a production site.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Do you know if I can upgrade manually? I tried upgrade to latest version, and I got some errors.

Comment: Best would be to think how to solve those errors. Maybe there is some timeout and upgrade should be processed on local server, maybe there are some issues with third-party modules, you should try to upgrade with developer mode enabled, of course using copy of your store, not a production one.

Answer (score 0):

During AJAX add to cart many checks are performed on DB, so make sure
to check and keep DB **ps_cart_rule** table as clean as possible, especially if you have many "automatic rules" without coupon code and/or not binded to specific conditions (id_customer etc.) or you are using third party module to massively generate cart rules.

Always perform regular manteinance by deleting expired / inactive cart rules from time to time and you'll see major improvements in TTFB when adding products to cart.